# Response rendering null (\u0) characters

Tags: php, html, laravel, response, whitespace

Why laravel blade view source code starts with null characters:

Route:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
     return view('home');
});
```

home.blade.php

```
<html>
   <head>
     <title>a</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>ee</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Output in Chrome:
[Console source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwnbr.jpg)

View page source: [Page source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErGKa.jpg)

A lot of white spaces added.

If I change routes to:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return response()->json(['a' => 'b']);
});
```

Page looks like:
[Web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6TdH.jpg)

In addition every ajax request fails and JSON.parse exception is thrown because of \u0 characters.

I'm stuck with this totally.

Comment: No idea why it does that for you. That's not normal behaviour. Source of exactly same json looks like [this](https://imgur.com/oyWRD8W) when I try it.